# How to identify last row insertion and provide response back Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Here in below code i am calling this insertTableDetailsRow(); in a for loop. Where insertTableDetailsRow method does insertion of row with each call from for loop into my sqlite3 db.

**Q.** For loop can have single insertion to n numbers of insertion. I want to provide a response back to client as soon last insertion is done to DB table. Since i am new to this node js and sqlite, it has made me to scratch my head over this problem. :P Any help would be appreciated.

```
function insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res)
    {   counterRun=1;
        db.serialize(function () 
        {   
            var stmt=db.prepare('INSERT INTO TestCaseDetails (TestCaseID,TestCaseDesc,Command,Co_ordinate,Verificarion) VALUES ($id,$desc,$cmd,$cord,$verf)', function (error) 
            {   if(error)
                {   
                    console.log("Error is "+error);
                    res.jsonp("Insertion Failed "+error);
                    res.end();
                    throw error;
                }
                else
                {
                    stmt.run(placeholders, function(err) {
                    if(err) 
                    {   
                        res.jsonp("Insertion Failed at row "+error);
                        res.end();
                        throw err;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        console.log(this.sql);
                        console.log(this.lastID);
                        console.log(this.changes);

                        stmt.finalize();
                        console.log(placeholders);
                        console.log(counterRun); // just for debug

                        counterRun++;
                    }
                            });
                }       
            });
        }); 
    }
```

### Method which has for loop and calls insertTableDetailsRow()

```
function addTestCaseDetailsDatabase(req, res) 
{
    responseResultOBJ=[];
    var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");

    var insertionlist = req.body.dataHolder;
    console.log("Selected New Data Length is  " + insertionlist.length+"    "+JSON.stringify(insertionlist));

    var dbName, repository, db;

    dbName = insertionlist[0].SelectedDB;
    console.log("Selected DB is " + dbName);

    repository = "./code/" + dbName + ".db";
    console.log("Final DB Repository is " + repository);

    db = new sqlite3.Database(repository);

    var caseId,caseDesc,cmd,cord,verf;

    caseId = insertionlist[1].caseID;
    console.log("Case ID is " + caseId);

    caseDesc = insertionlist[2].description;
    console.log("Case Desc is " + caseDesc);

    for (var i = 3; i <= insertionlist.length ; i++) 
    {   
        if((i+1)==insertionlist.length || (i+2)==insertionlist.length)
        {       
            break;
        }
            cmd = insertionlist[(i)].command;
            cord = insertionlist[(i+1)].cordinates;
            verf = insertionlist[(i+2)].verification;

        if((cmd !== undefined && cord !== undefined && verf !== undefined))
        {
            if(i==3)
            {
            //console.log("Current Statement1 "+caseId+"   "+caseDesc+"    "+cmd+"    "+cord+"    "+verf);

            var placeholders =  {
                    $id: caseId,
                    $desc: caseDesc,
                    $cmd: cmd,
                    $cord: cord,
                    $verf: verf
                            };

            insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res) ;
            stmt="";
            }
            else
            {
            //console.log("Current Statement "+cmd+"    "+cord+"    "+verf);
            var blank="";
            var placeholders =  {
                    $id: blank,
                    $desc: caseDesc,
                    $cmd: cmd,
                    $cord: cord,
                    $verf: verf
                            };

            insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res) ;
            stmt="";
            }
        }   
    }

    console.log("Insertion was a success ");
    res.jsonp("Testcases Added successfully"); //This get printed even before any                      insertions are made
    res.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for two days and doing some research i got answer to this question and its working fine with it. Thanks to [this](http://metaduck.com/01-asynchronous-iteration-patterns.html) link.

Since its node js, database insertions are most probably asynchronous and to keep its nature of asynchronous intact and to not change the insertion order i used serialize().

For my case, i wanted to notify client only if all insertion are successfully but i was stuck as if how to identify last insertion.

I passed on an additional parameter insertions which has data for number of insertions that gonna take place. And compared this with counter value inside insertTableDetailsRow();.

Going ahead i added new method callInsertionPassed() which has select query to fetch data from db where successful insertion are done and return it client as soon all insertions are  done.

Find below code for reference:

```
function addTestCaseDetailsDatabase(req, res) 
{
    responseResultOBJ=[];
    var sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");

    var insertionlist = req.body.dataHolder;
    console.log("Selected New Data Length is  " + insertionlist.length+"    "+JSON.stringify(insertionlist));

    var dbName, repository, db;

    dbName = insertionlist[0].SelectedDB;
    console.log("Selected DB is " + dbName);

    repository = "./code/" + dbName + ".db";
    console.log("Final DB Repository is " + repository);

    db = new sqlite3.Database(repository);

    var caseId,caseDesc,cmd,cord,verf;

    caseId = insertionlist[1].caseID;
    console.log("Case ID is " + caseId);

    caseDesc = insertionlist[2].description;
    console.log("Case Desc is " + caseDesc);

    //Identifying number of insertion based on this final call back would be done
    var insertions=0;
    for (var x = 3; x < insertionlist.length ; x++) 
    {
        if(insertionlist[(x)].command !== undefined)
        insertions++;
    }
    console.log("Insertion list length is "+insertions);

    //Extracting data from json data object coming from clint side that would be inserted later
    for (var i = 3; i <= insertionlist.length ; i++) 
    {   
        if((i+1)==insertionlist.length || (i+2)==insertionlist.length)
        {       
            break;
        }
            cmd = insertionlist[(i)].command;
            cord = insertionlist[(i+1)].cordinates;
            verf = insertionlist[(i+2)].verification;

            //console.log("OK "+insertionlist[(i)].command+"  "+insertionlist[(i)].cordinates+"   "+insertionlist[(i)].verification);

        if((cmd !== undefined && cord !== undefined && verf !== undefined))
        {
            if(i==3)
            {
            //console.log("Current Statement1 "+caseId+"   "+caseDesc+"    "+cmd+"    "+cord+"    "+verf);

            var placeholders =  {
                    $id: caseId,
                    $desc: caseDesc,
                    $cmd: cmd,
                    $cord: cord,
                    $verf: verf
                            };

            insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res,insertions) ;
            stmt="";
            }
            else
            {
            //console.log("Current Statement "+cmd+"    "+cord+"    "+verf);
            var blank="";
            var placeholders =  {
                    $id: blank,
                    $desc: caseDesc,
                    $cmd: cmd,
                    $cord: cord,
                    $verf: verf
                            };

            insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res,insertions) ;
            stmt="";
            }
        }   
    }
    console.log("Insertion was a success ");
}
```

**********************************Method for Insertion and Rollback if any error comes**********

```
var serialList=[];
 function insertTableDetailsRow(db,placeholders,res,insertions)
{   counterRun=1;
    db.serialize(function () 
    {   
        var stmt=db.prepare('INSERT INTO TestCaseDetails (TestCaseID,TestCaseDesc,Command,Co_ordinate,Verificarion) VALUES ($id,$desc,$cmd,$cord,$verf)', function (error) 
        {   if(error)
            {   
                console.log("Error is "+error);
                res.jsonp("Problem with framing SQL Query or DB itself "+error);
                res.end();
                //throw error;
            }
            else
            {
                stmt.run(placeholders, function(err) {
                if(err) 
                {   
                    res.jsonp("Problem while Inserting a Row Data or DB itself "+error);
                    res.end();

                    if(counterRun !== 1)
                    {
                        for(var selection=0;selection<serialList.length;selection++)
                        {
                            var stmtDEL="DELETE FROM TestCaseDetails WHERE SrNo = (" + serialList[selection] + ")";
                            console.log("Delete Statement from failed insertion"+stmtDEL);
                            db.serialize(function () 
                            {
                                db.all(stmtDEL, function(error) 
                                {
                                    if(error)
                                    {
                                        console.log("Fatal Exception occured while Rolling back DEL for Serial ID"+serialList[selection]);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        console.log("Successfully rolledback all insertions");

                                    }
                                });
                            }); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    console.log(this.sql);
                    console.log(this.lastID);

                    serialList.push(this.lastID);

                    console.log(this.changes);

                    stmt.finalize();
                    console.log(placeholders);
                    console.log(counterRun); //printing just for reference

                    if(counterRun==insertions)  //All insertion are done succesfully
                    {   
                        callInsertionPassed(db,serialList,res);   // In near future it will be added if needed
                        serialList=[];
                    }

                    counterRun++;                   
                }
                        });
            }       
        });
    }); 
}
```

***********************************Method to select current insertions and notify client for successful insertion*********************

```
function callInsertionPassed(db,serialList,res)
{   
    console.log("OK "+serialList);
    var result=1;
    for(var selection=0;selection<serialList.length;selection++)
    {   
        console.log("Selection is "+serialList[selection]);
        // Firing Select Query to confirm if insertion is done sucessfully
        var selectQuery="SELECT * FROM TestCaseDetails WHERE SrNo=("+serialList[selection]+")";
        db.get(selectQuery, function(err, row) 
        {
            if(err == null && typeof(row) != 'undefined')
            {
                //console.log(selectQuery);
                console.log("Selected results "+row.TestCaseID + ": " + row.Command);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Data fetching error arrived for Serial ID "+serialList[selection]);  // If this came its db error
                res.jsonp("Testcases Saved Successfully but some internal DB error arised pls contact DEV team with Error No: Select004");
            }
        });
    }
    res.jsonp("Saved "+(serialList.length)+" Test Steps Successfully");
    res.end();
    serialList=[];
}
```